# How to use Custom Certificate for SQL Server Availability Group Endpoint Authentication

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, certificate

I am setting up a SQL Server Availability Group using the commands provided in the Microsoft documentation. The process involves creating a certificate, backing it up with the private key, and restoring it on all replicas for endpoint creation and authentication.

However, I would like to use my custom self-signed certificate and private key for this purpose.
I have generated my certificate and private key using openssl.

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout root_ca.key -out root_ca.crt -subj "/CN=RootCA/O=MyOrganization"
```

Creating the certificate:

```
CREATE CERTIFICATE server_certificate
FROM FILE = '/var/opt/mssql/root_ca.crt'
WITH PRIVATE KEY (FILE = '/var/opt/mssql/root_ca.key');
```

When I attempt to use my certificate generated by OpenSSL, I encounter the error:

> The certificate, asymmetric key, or private key file is not valid or does not exist; or you do not have permissions for it.

What steps should I follow to successfully use my certificate in this scenario?

Any insights or guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Needs to be in PKCS12 or PFX format

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Can you share some more information?
I have created the certificate and key using 
` openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout root_ca.key -out root_ca.crt -subj "/CN=RootCA/O=MyOrg" `

Then converted to PKCS12 format using 
` openssl pkcs12 -export -out root_ca.pfx -inkey root_ca.key -in root_ca.crt ` 

```
USE master;
CREATE CERTIFICATE SqlServerCert
FROM FILE = '/var/opt/mssql/sql_server.pfx'
WITH  
   PRIVATE KEY (
      FILE = '/var/opt/mssql/sql_server.pfx'
);
``` 
Still getting the same error.